# Updating pip package in virtual env via cron

Tags: python, cron, ubuntu-14.04, virtualenv

I'm not sure why this is happening, I currently have this set up in my `crontab -e`

```
*/30 * * * * cd /home/www/ && source env/bin/activate && pip install --upgrade youtube_dl >/dev/null 2>&1
```

The problem is this is not actually updating the script.  When I run just

```
cd /home/www/ && source env/bin/activate && pip install --upgrade youtube_dl >/dev/null 2>&1
```

in terminal it upgrades, but when it runs via cron it does not.

Should I break it up into a bash script to guarantee success? I was under the impression if I could run the command in terminal with success it should also execute with success on crontab.

Comment: Have you checked these yet? http://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work

Comment: yes, checked those.  Permissions are set, other crontab's work fine.  If I take out the virtual env it runs fine and updates, just seems to be when under the virtual enviroment

Comment: The ones about having full paths for commands and sh instead of bash might apply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cron uses `/bin/sh` as its shell, not bash.  you are calling `source`, which is a bash command.

note: you can replace `source` with `.`, and both shells will recognize the command.